# Extremely slow import of matplotlib afm

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, adobe

Import time is unacceptably long:

```
  from matplotlib import pylab as plt --> 3.0124739 secs
```

This is the output of cProfile, which clearly shows the problem being afm.py, which is some interface for [Adobe Font Metrics.](http://matplotlib.org/api/afm_api.html). Matplotlib version is 1.4.0 - Ubuntu 14.04

```
         5994612 function calls (5992123 primitive calls) in 4.702 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      182    1.589    0.009    2.372    0.013 afm.py:220(_parse_kern_pairs)
      215    0.746    0.003    1.420    0.007 afm.py:180(_parse_char_metrics)
  1297990    0.410    0.000    0.410    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
   839978    0.288    0.000    0.288    0.000 {method 'readline' of 'file' objects}
        2    0.254    0.127    4.185    2.093 font_manager.py:544(createFontList)
   843308    0.170    0.000    0.170    0.000 {method 'startswith' of 'str' objects}
   114276    0.168    0.000    0.205    0.000 afm.py:72(_to_list_of_floats)
1563800      0.125    0.000    0.125    0.000 {len}
   839220    0.117    0.000    0.117    0.000 {method 'rstrip' of 'str' objects}
   115290    0.116    0.000    0.119    0.000 {method 'decode' of 'str' objects}
   117775    0.086    0.000    0.086    0.000 afm.py:56(_to_int)
       20    0.061    0.003    0.061    0.003 {built-in method poll}
      520    0.040    0.000    0.040    0.000 {method 'get_sfnt' of 'FT2Font' objects}
     6910    0.036    0.000    0.036    0.000 {posix.stat}
     3372    0.025    0.000    0.038    0.000 posixpath.py:336(normpath)
```

Any idea how to fix/disable it?

**EDIT**:

Rolling back to 1.3.1 saved my day. Running time is now 0.2 secs.

Comment: Any idea why the rollback works? Did you file a bug report with matplotlib developers?

Comment: @JoErNanO, I have no idea, sorry, and yes I filed a bug report here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3655

Comment: actually cannot replicate, first time importing after installing  took a while but now importing instantly. matplotlib 1.4.0 on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Sorry, the `import pylab as plt` is painful.  You should be doing `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `import numpy as np`

Comment: If you fixed your problem, you can place an answer yourself and accept it. (if you feel that you don't deserve the points, just set it as a wiki-answer)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem. I figured out, that this happens when you upgrade `matplotlib` to a newer version. The font cache file is not compatible with the new version, but apparently is not recreated. Instead font list is created each time on the fly. The solution is to delete the matplotlib cache directory (in my case `~/.cache/matplotlib`)

Comment: What is the cache directory in a Windows pip installation?
EDIT: Ah, with ~ you mean the current directory (like, the Python dir)?

Comment: I had a similar problem on macOS in which a number of fonts were symbolic links, and there was a mutual nesting of the links, which was causing a very slow start of either importing `pylab`, or starting `sympy`. Removing the offending links from the `~/Library/Fonts` folder solved it.